# ¿SE PUEDE HACER UN DEPLOY EN PRODUCTION DE UNA APP EN NODEJS SIN USAR APACHE2 NI NGINX?

Tags: nodejs

Quisiera saber si se puede hacer un deploy de nodejs sin necesidad de usar apache2 ni nginx , solo correr el server en el puerto especifico

Comment: Por favor edita tu título y evita usar mayúsculas, pareciera que gritas

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te invito a leer [ask] ya realizar el [tour]. Respecto a tu pregunta, aparte de ser una terrible idea (por cuestiones de seguridad y desempeño), claro que sí puedes hacerlo. Creo que la pregunta es realmente ¿deberías hacerlo? y para esa pregunta la respuesta es **NO**. Saludos